# 1987 Schwinn Tempo Maillard hub rear axle

Tags: hub, axle, rear-wheel

I have a 1987 Schwinn Tempo with 32h Maillard "Sealed mechanism" hubs. (I'm still confused about that phrase, maybe it's a bad translation? They're completely unsealed cup-cone hubs). The axle is slightly bent near the drive side, and maybe it's distended or maybe just the axle, but the cone no longer fits flush. I can still adjust it to spin freely and with no axle play, but the freewheel and rim wobble. I am looking for either an axle or a donor hub I can take the cup from. What is the thread diameter of these axles? Wheels Mfg has nice looking rear axles which are advertised as "Shimano/ fits most japanese hubs" or "Fits most Taiwanese hubs", and ebay has a plethora of 36h hubs of the same vintage which look extremely similar. Would I be able to use the cones and axles from 36h hubs?

[image: 1987 Schwinn Tempo Maillard Rear hub]

Comment: In case it's helpful: the dropouts are 128mm, six speed freewheel.  According to Sheldon Brown I should be looking for axle that's 10-11mm longer than the spacing, so I am looking for 137mm axles in particular.

Comment: Axle diameter: 9.5 x 26 TPI should I stock up?  seems to be a pretty rare length/dia/thread combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the axle has worked, but the new axle takes un-keyed washers.  It's much harder to adjust pre-load correctly between the cone, washers, locknut, and quick-release.  Bikeforums.net suggest these hubs are garbage, so I am looking into building a new wheel.